# Minimalistic reimplementation of std::cout

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, operator-overloading

Can you please help me reimplement the most basic functionality of std::cout?

Requirements:

1) C standard headers can be included, but no C++ libraries can be used. For example stdio.h can be used for printf function.

2) It is okay if it only works with one type, let's go with "char*". The objective is to find the briefest implementation.

3) The following line should be working without any modification (namespace should be used):

```
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

4) Everything should be within one file including the main() method

Edit:

Here is the code which I have, that results in a compilation error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace std {
  class cout {
    public:
      void operator << (char* s) {
        printf("%s", s);
      }
  };
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; // Compilation error: expected an identifier
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not even good performance is an objective. I just think, it would be a good lesson for people who start learning c++, because even the "hello world" c++ application contains a lot of things (syntactic advancements) which are not very easy to grasp.

Comment: This isn't a crowdsourced homework solver

Comment: No one will provide you code. You can ask for help not for code. Would be better if you delete question otherwise you will only get downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, you were not refering with an operator to the object, but to the class type. You need to create an object of that type to use the << with it.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

//don't ever use std namespace
namespace test {
    class base_cout {
    public:
        void operator << (const char const* s) {
            printf("%s",s);
        }
    };

    // This should be extern if you want to use it outside a single file.
    base_cout cout;
}

int main() {
    test::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

This is what cout in iostream header is:
`namespace std { extern ostream __declspec(dllexport) cout; }`

Comment: Thanks. Now that you mentioned that I can add the "extern" keyword in the line of the "cout" variable definition, could you please help me construct what should be the additional first line in "main.cpp" file if the "main" function were defined in a separate "main.cpp" file? (The line you extracted from iostream header does not work, even after I rename the namespace and class names.)